# Flip and spin function in CSS3 not working on Firefox

Tags: jquery, css

I have this cute rotating and flipping button activated on click. It works fine in Google Chrome (and Microsoft Edge for that matter), but as soon as I try and fire it up in Firefox, the click makes the button move a teeny-tiny bit and then go back. I do not understand why.

Here's my CSS:

```
.spinner {
      width: 120px;
      height: 120px;
      background: url('down.png');
      margin-left:auto;
      margin-right:auto;
      -webkit-animation: sk-rotateplane 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
      animation: sk-rotateplane 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes sk-rotateplane {
      0% { -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) }
      50% { -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg) }
      100% { -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg)  rotateX(180deg) }
    }

    @keyframes sk-rotateplane {
      0% { 
        transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) 
      } 50% { 
        transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180.1deg) rotateY(0deg);
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180.1deg) rotateY(0deg) 
      } 100% { 
        transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(-179.9deg);
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(-179.9deg);
      }

    }
```

EDIT: I did not investigate the problem properly. It's the `onClick` jQuery that is broken somehow, it doesn't work in Firefox on my site..

```
<!-- HTML -->
<button id="reload" onclick="return returnGame();clearDescr();">
</button>

<!-- The .js file -->
$("#theSpinner").removeClass("spinner");
$("#theSpinner").addClass("notspinning");
```

Other jQuery from the same file works..

Comment: it works fine for me in firefox also  [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/2zumoLqa/)

Comment: It works fine for me also in firefox https://jsfiddle.net/2zumoLqa/

Comment: @John Smith please test it again or if you still facing same error then please let us know the version of your Firefox..

Comment: @SunilGehlot Updated. My bad.

Comment: Hey, are you looking for this? http://output.jsbin.com/poharusiti

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its works for me too. Anyway define the FF version of the animation and transform

```
  @-moz-keyframes sk-rotateplane { 

  }
```

and

```
 -moz-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180.1deg) rotateY(0deg);
```

```css
.spinner {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background: url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150');
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  -webkit-animation: sk-rotateplane 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: sk-rotateplane 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes sk-rotateplane {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px)
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg) rotateX(180deg)
  }
}
@keyframes sk-rotateplane {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg)
  }
  50% {
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180.1deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180.1deg) rotateY(0deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(-179.9deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(-179.9deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="spinner">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add

```
-moz-animation:
```

&

```
-moz-transform:
```

everywhere because older Firefox uses `-moz-`